# How do I drop a very specific table in Postgresql (public.pg_ts_parser vs. pg_catalog.pg_ts_parser)?

Tags: postgresql

I am having a problem upgrading my Postgresql 9.2 database to 9.4. The problem I have is that I have these tables that are incompatible for an upgrade:

```
public.pg_ts_dict.dict_init
public.pg_ts_dict.dict_lexize
public.pg_ts_parser.prs_start
public.pg_ts_parser.prs_nexttoken
public.pg_ts_parser.prs_end
public.pg_ts_parser.prs_headline
public.pg_ts_parser.prs_lextype
```

Postgresql says that I should delete these tables and the upgrade should work. I am currently trying to figure out how to do this.

Postgresql has `pg_catalog.pg_ts_parser` and `pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict`. These are system catalogs and can absolutely not be removed, nor do I want to. I want to remove the `public.pg_ts_*` tables.

More specifically I want to dump the tables, upgrade the database, and then restore both `public.pg_ts_parser and public.pg_ts_dict`. However every time I try to dump or drop the tables, it defaults to the system catalog. Which I don't want. How can I specify these exact tables? Thanks for any help in advance.

-------EDIT------

Here are the commands I am running to dump the tables.

```
pg_dump -Fc -t public.pg_ts_dict -t public.pg_ts_parser > file.dump

pg_dump: No matching tables were found
```

Here is a variation

```
pg_dump -Fc -t pg_ts_dict -t pg_ts_parser > file.dump
```

The second variation contains the dump of the system catalog pg_ts_dict and parser not the public version. However, it is very confusing because the contents of the file.dump contains these lines of code among @ signs and ^ signs.

```
DROP TABLE pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict;


    ^@^@^@pg_catalog^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@postgres^@^D^@^@^@true^A^A^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^G^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@0^@^A^@^@^@0^@
^@^@^@pg_ts_dict^@^C^@^@^@ACL^@^A^@^@^@^@<86>^@^@^@REVOKE ALL ON TABLE pg_ts_dict FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE pg_ts_dict FROM postgres;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE pg_ts_dict TO PUBLIC;
^@^@^@^@^@^A^A^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@pg_catalog^A^A^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@postgres^@^E^@^@^@false^@^B^@^@^@54^A^A^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@7^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@1259^@^D^@^@^@3601^@^L^@^@^@pg_ts_parser^@^E^@^@^@TABLE^@^B^@^@^@^@ö^@^@^@CREATE TABLE pg_ts_parser (
    prsname name NOT NULL,
    prsnamespace oid NOT NULL,
    prsstart regproc NOT NULL,
    prstoken regproc NOT NULL,
    prsend regproc NOT NULL,
    prsheadline regproc NOT NULL,
    prslextype regproc NOT NULL
```

Not sure what to make of this.

Comment: "*However every time I try to dump or drop the tables, it defaults to the system catalog*" how exactly are you dumping those tables. What happens when you explicitly use the schema name to export them, e.g.: `copy public.pg_ts_dict to 'dict.csv'` or `copy public.pg_ts_parser to 'parser.csv'`?

Comment: Cross-post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/114284/1822

Comment: Thanks for the reply a_horse_with_no_name. I'll edit my post and add that, that's an important piece I should elaborate on.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name. My apologies, It just occurred to me you meant the PGSQL copy command, not what I posted. Here is the input/output. COPY pg_ts_parser to home/postgres/parser.csv  ---> COPY 1 

COPY public.pg_ts_parser to home/postgres/parser.csv ----> COPY 0

Comment: It looks like it doesn't exist, but it clearly does.

Comment: Wait ... `public.pg_ts_dict.dict_init` ... The table name is supposed to be "pg_ts_dict.dict_init"? The name including the dot - which is a very unfortunate, but legal name. Please add the verbatim output of this query to your question: `SELECT schemaname, tablename, tableowner
FROM   pg_tables
WHERE  tablename ILIKE '%pg_ts_%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call should actually work as is:

```
pg_dump -Fc -t public.pg_ts_dict -t public.pg_ts_parser > file.dump
```

You can use a wildcard to include all tables starting with `pg_ts_`.

```
pg_dump -Fc -t 'public.pg_ts_*' > file.dump
```

On the Linux shell, you may need the extra quotes. [(Related question on dba.SE.)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/112392/3684) Remove the quotes in Windows.

To make it abundantly clear you could exclude the same tables from `pg_catalog` explicitly. Normally, this is *not* necessary, but something seems to be abnormal in your case.

```
pg_dump -Fc -t 'public.pg_ts_*' -T 'pg_catalog.pg_ts_*' > file.dump
```

[The documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html)

> Also, you must write something like `-t sch.tab` to select a table in a
>   particular schema, rather than the old locution of `-n sch -t tab`.

Comment: Hey Erwin. Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate this alternative command. I've tried it but I still notice that my newly created dump file has this reference to the pg_catalog. Inside the file are the lines DROP TABLE pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict and DROP TABLE pg_catalog.pg_ts_parser; What do you think? Would you agree that it tried a dump on the pg_catalog version or the public version?

Comment: Hey Erwin, I tested my hypothesis. I created a blank database and then tried to restore the dump file onto the new database. What I received was this error [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "pg_ts_dict" already exists. I also had this for parser, so it seems to me that the dump command is trying to grab the pg_catalog version. I wish there was a way I can definitely know.

Comment: @DanRubio: I am sorry, my first version was incorrect.

Comment: I wanted to note that I had forgotten the dbname parameter to pg_dump.